# How to convert cc to bar?

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, pressure, temperature, density

In astronomy/astrophysics, medium density is often given in *[cc](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/679/how-does-interstellar-matter-density-vary)*, particles per cubic centimeter. Also, the temperature of the medium is usually given, in Kelvins.

For some materials the melting point differs significantly even at very low pressures; water melts at $10\mu{bar}$ in about 230K while at $1\mu{bar}$ its melting point is close to [1K](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60170/freezing-point-of-water-with-respect-to-pressure). And the pressure is given in common pressure units - bar, Pascals etc.

So, if I want to know the melting points of various materials in space (and various areas of it), using common phase-temperature-presure diagrams (possibly extrapolating a little), I need to find the 'ambient pressure' of the inter[planetary|stellar|galactic] medium in units the graph is in, usually bar.

How can I calculate the gas pressure given particles per cubic centimeter, and its temperature in Kelvin?

Comment: Typically, one uses the ideal gas law $p=n k_BT$ (or $p=\rho k_BT/\mu m_H$ where $\mu$ is the mean molecular weight and $m_H$ is the mass of a hydrogen atom).

Comment: The triple point pressure for water is 6 millibar.  If the pressure is lower than that, there is no liquid phase at any temperature, no melting point

Comment: @KyleKanos  your comment came up just as I editted

Comment: @KyleKanos sorry just figured it out - I will delete my comment and apologize --- quick question - any reason you didn't post it as answer? I was typing an answer but you should do it.... I will happily upvote your answer

Comment: @tom: no apologies needed. I guess the third paragraph aspect had me a little off. If you've got an answer going, go ahead and post it.

Comment: @DavePhD: A misnomer... temperature at which ice ceases to be ice (whatever it turns into).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I calculate the gas pressure given particles per cubic centimeter, and its temperature in Kelvin?

as pointed out in comment by KyleKanos

$$pV=Nk_\mathrm BT$$

where $p$ is pressure, $V$ is volume (in $\mathrm{m^3}$), $N$ is the number of particles, $k_\mathrm B$ is Botzmann's constant and $T$ is temperature *in Kelvin*.

If you rearrange it

$$p= \frac NVk_\mathrm BT$$

so you can use this to convert to particles per volume to pressure, but note that volume units in the equation are $\mathrm{m^3}$ so you need to convert from $\mathrm{cm^3}$ (multiply by $10^6$).

Comment: Well, you could just use CGS and convert using 1 dyne/cm^2 = 1e-6 bar.